# How to filter results by city?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am using DBpedia to retrieve data on specific towns' POIs, for instance Barcelona. I've tried to find appropriate answers to my problems on Stack Overflow but almost all the answers provided did not work out for me, and given that I am new in SPARQL, I couldn't manage to figure out whether or not it was the syntax that was at fault or if there was something else. I am using the DBpedia SPARQL Endpoint available at the following address : http://dbpedia.org/sparql

I've tried to use some things such as `?citylabel` or `?location`, and to either use the `FILTER` command or directly fill a value for these classes. I've also tried a few other things, without satisfying results (and most of the times syntax errors that I could not resolve). These solutions have been, in most cases, applied and seemed to work just fine for people, so I do not understand what's going on.

```
BASE    <http://www.dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia3: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT (SAMPLE(?label) as ?activity_name)
  (SAMPLE(?latitude) as ?activity_lat)
  (SAMPLE(?longitude) as ?activity_lon)
  (SAMPLE(?homepage) as ?URL)
  (SAMPLE(?type) as ?activity_type)
  (SAMPLE(?abstract) as ?descriptor)

WHERE
 { ?Museum a dbo:Museum ;
           rdfs:label ?label ;
           dbo:abstract ?abstract ;
           dbo:type ?type ;
           geo:lat ?latitude ;
           geo:long ?longitude ;
           foaf:homepage ?homepage .
 }

GROUP BY ?Museum ?label
```

The results of this query are, I think, pretty much any museum that is known by DBpedia and categorized as such. What I'd like to have is a list of museums within Barcelona. Can somebody give me an rather in-depth answer so I can understand how it is working ? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: not sure what exactly you did as you didn't show the filters but it's simply checking for the location, i.e. `?Museum a dbo:Museum ; dbo:location dbr:Barcelona ;`

Comment: Ok, this is working quite well. Thank you very much.